# Losing Javascript Functionality on innerHtml

Tags: jquery, html, google-apps-script, datepicker, innerhtml

I'm trying to create an html-based application through Google Apps Script which has a constant header and navigation and then applies content from pulled files into a third dynamic part of the page.

It was all going well, until I try to insert input fields to which I want JQuery applied. This is a learning project for me, but I'm completely lost here. Below are reproduced the pertinent parts of the script.

My question is, I'm using the JQuery plugin datepicker for some boxes on a form. Now on the page pulled from index.html by the first doGet function in the code.gs file, it all works perfectly, then if I click to load the newcust.html file, after it is inserted (via innerhtml) to the dynamic  element, the datepicker plugin doesn't work any more on the newly inserted content (like the one under the label 'Start Date'). The date input box itself loads, as does the rest of newcust.html, but it is now just a standard text box.

Also, this is my first project, so forgive me if my coding style is bad.

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
.setTitle('GAS Application').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
return html;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CSS').getContent(); ?>

<div id="top-banner">
<img src="bannertop.png" width="900" />
</div>

<div id="main-content">
<div id="navigation">
<div id="menu"><ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="Home" class="link1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="drop link2">Edit<!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul style="height:72px;top:0px;">
            <li><a href="#" id="NewCust" class="link2a">New Customer/Quote</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="EditCust" class="link2b">Edit Customer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="DeleteCust" class='link2c'>Delete Customer</a></li>
        </ul>
        </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="page-wrap">
<div id="dynamic" class="">
<h3 align="center">Home</h3>

<p>Home Page Text</p> 

<p>Please select a date below :</p>

click here : <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" />
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>

<script>
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 1,
 });
</script>

<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 $( "#GoHome" ).add( "#NewCust" ).add( "#EditCust" ).add( "#DeleteCust").click(function() {
 var incoming = this.id;
 pushPageData(incoming);
}

function pushPageData(e) {
if (e == 'NewCust') {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatePage).insertNewCust();}
else if (e == 'EditCust') {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatePage).insertEditCust();}
else if (e == 'DeleteCust') {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatePage).insertDeleteCust();}
 }  // these point to separate .gs files, I'll reproduce one below

function updatePage(data) {                   

var inframe = document.getElementById('dynamic');
inframe.innerHTML = data;
}

</script>
```

**newcust.gs**

```
function insertNewCust() {

var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('newcust').getContent();
return html;
}
```

**newcust.html**

```
<h3>Add New Customer or Quote</h3>

<table class='first'><tr><td>
<form name='newcustomer' id='newcustomer'> 
<fieldset>
<legend>General Information </legend>

<div class='col15'>
 <label for='title'>Title:</label>
  <select class='dropdown' name='title'>
     <option value=''></option>
     <option>Mr</option>
     <option>Mrs</option>
     <option>Miss</option>
     <option>Ms</option>
     <option>Dr</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class='col25'>
    <label for='firstname'>First Name:</label>
    <input name='firstname' type='text' style="default">
 </div>
 <div class='col25'>
    <label for='surname'>Surname:</label>
    <input name='surname' type='text' style="default">
 </div>
     <div style="clear: both; height: 5px;"></div>
  <div class='col50'>
    <label for='address'>Address:</label>
     <input name='address1' type='text' placeholder="House Name/No. & Street" style="wide" size="40">
      <input name='address2' type='text' placeholder="Estate" style="wide" size="40">
      <input name='addresstown' type='text' placeholder="Town/City" style="wide" size="25">
      <input name='addresspost' type='text' placeholder="Postcode" style="wide" size="10">
     </div>
     <div class='col20'>
     <label for='tel'>Telephone:</label>
     <input name='tel' type='text' size="15" class='tel'>
     </div>
  <div class='col25'>
  <label for='email'>Email:</label>
   <input name='email' type='text' size="25" placeholder='example@gmail.com'>
  </div>
  <div class='col15hide'>
     <label for='startdate'>Start Date:</label>
      <input type="text" name="startdate" id="datepicker" size="12" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  </td></tr></table>
```

*CSS File not included*

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that you're calling jQuery on your index.html file but not in newcust.html(once you change pages, jQuery is no longer being invoked). You're either going to have to include jQuery in a file that is always part of the DOM, or duplicate your jQuery links into the newcust.html file.

Comment: How would I go about making it always part of the DOM then? I figured that since the newcust.html is inserted within index.html, that the same scripts would be used. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, spent about 2 hours essentially trying to imagine how this loads in the memory and realised that when the jQuery $( '#datepicker' ) bit of code runs, it must create a map of all existing elements with that id, and since my second page elements don't exist at the time, they are left off the map, this the function isn't applied to them.

So it may not be pretty, but I just repeated the code again after my new html has been inserted into the page, thus seemingly mapping the new input elements to the function. Also taken the advice here and migrated all of my scripts out of the html files. Thanks though, you guys certainly pushed me in the right direction.

**index.html**

```
function updatePage(data) {                   

  var inframe = document.getElementById('dynamic');
  inframe.innerHTML = data;


  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
   });
}
```